# How to get stateAndRef from a contract state?

Tags: java, kotlin, state, corda

I am trying to get the stateAndRef pair from a contractState object. I need this in order to add my output state into a new command as an input state. *Is there a way to do this*?

Answer (score 1):

My walk around to this is the following:

```
val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

val testStateAndRef = StateAndRef(TransactionState(yourState, notary = notary), StateRef(yourState.hash(), 0))
```

Above demonstrates how to transform yourState of type contractState to stateAndRef pair